# Using jq to append output generated from Ansible template

Tags: json, ansible

I am writing Ansible play, one of the tasks is to append entry to a JSON document. E.g.

JSON document `staff.json`:

```
{
   "staff":[
      {
         "john":[
            {
               "position":"techwriter"
            },
            {
               "sex":"male"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to append this entry to `staff`:

```
{
   "staff":[
      {
         "john":[
            {
               "position":"techwriter"
            },
            {
               "sex":"male"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "jane":[
            {
               "position":"admin"
            },
            {
               "sex":"female"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The entry would be generated from Ansible [`template`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html), something like this:

```
      {
         "{{ staff_name }}":[
            {
               "position":"{{ staff_position }}"
            },
            {
               "sex":"{{ staff_sex }}"
            }
         ]
      }
```

I've learned to use `jq` to [append entry](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) to the JSON document, as seen in "[Add json array element with jq (cmdline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414854/add-json-array-element-with-jq-cmdline)". However, I do not know how I can implement this in Ansible, as template would output to a file.

I need a solution of something like this:

```
cat staff.json | jq '.staff |= .+ ["OUTPUT_FROM_TEMPLATE"]'
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: I'm removing the jq tag since you're not asking for a jq solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `template` lookup plugin:

```
    - shell: cat staff.json | jq '.staff |= . + [{{ item | to_json }}]' > staff.json
      with_template: person.j2
      vars:
        staff_name: jane
        staff_position: admin
        staff_sex: female
```

Note that you need to use `to_json` filter with `item`, because Ansible template engine converts json strings that it can evaluate into dict.

Comment: Works like a charm! I did not know `with_template` exist, hard to dig from Ansible doc either. However, `> staff.json` does not work for me. I had to use `| tee staff.json`