# Adding a new array to already existing JSON file jq bash

Tags: json, shell, jq

Assume I have the following large json

```
    {
    "firsttag": {
    "secondtag": [
      {
        "thirdtag": [
          {
            "someothertag": [
              {
                "sample":"else"
              },
              {                    
                "targetBlank": true,                    
              }
            ],            
            "interestingtag": [
              {
                "refId": "A",
                "target": "abc",
              },
              {
                "refId": "B",
                "target": "bbb",
              },
              {
                "refId": "C",
                "target": "ccc",
              }
            ],                
          },
      },
  "overwrite": true
}
```

My JSON might not be syntactically perfect but that's becuase I've edited out some stuff. Now what I want to do is, I want to add another input under `interestingtag` that's similar to the others. For example, I desire it like

```
"interestingtag": [
              {
                "refId": "A",
                "target": "abc"
              },
              {
                "refId": "B",
                "target": "bbb"
              },
              {
                "refId": "C",
                "target": "ccc"
              },
              {
                "refId": "D",
                "target": "ddd"
              }
            ],
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to do it. I can retrieve the right location using

```
jq '.firsttag.secondtag[0].thirdtag[0].interestingtag' myfile.json
```

But when I try the simple

```
jq '.firsttag.secondtag[0].thirdtag[0].interestingtag + {"refId": "D", "refID": "C"}' myfile.json
```

I get a

```
jq: error: array and object cannot be added
```

Any idea how I can do this? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` does not append elements to arrays. You want to merge arrays using `|= .+ [...]` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414854/add-json-array-element-with-jq-cmdline)

```
jq '.firsttag.secondtag[0].thirdtag[0].interestingtag |= .+ [{"refId": "D", "refID": "C"}]' myfile.json
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had a look through your link but wasn't sure if I could add in an array within the []. The post only spoke about a single value. Thanks a ton, worked like a charm!

Comment: Rather than updating the array to add to the array `|= . + [...]`, just add to the array: `+= [...]`