# How concatenate multiple json objects with a delimiter comma using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Here is my data:

```
{
  "ReferringUrl": "N",
  "OpenAccess": "0",
  "ItmId": "1694738780"
}
{
  "ReferringUrl": "L",
  "OpenAccess": "1",
  "ItmId": "1347809133"
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
[
 {
  "ReferringUrl": "N",
  "OpenAccess": "0",
  "ItmId": "1694738780"
 },
 {
   "ReferringUrl": "L",
   "OpenAccess": "1",
   "ItmId": "1347809133"
 }
]
```

How to make it by using jq library? I use bash. Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add json array element with jq (cmdline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414854/add-json-array-element-with-jq-cmdline)

Comment: You should make some effort to solve this yourself, and include those attempts in your question, including what went wrong with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a JSON object stream into an array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404575/how-to-convert-a-json-object-stream-into-an-array-with-jq)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming the sequence of JSON objects is in a file named input.json, simply "slurp" it:

```
jq -s . input.json
```

If the objects are spread over multiple files, say `input*.json`, you can run: `jq -s . input*.json`.

#### Handling invalid JSON

If the "objects" are as originally shown (i.e., not strictly valid as JSON), then you could use a command-line tool such as `any-json`, `json5`, or `hjson` to convert them to JSON, one at a time.  If there is more than one quasi-JSON object per file, then you might be able to use `csplit` or `awk` to split up the file.

Alternatively, if the objects follow the pattern established in the example, you could use GNU sed: `sed -z 's/,\(\n}\)/\1/g'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP appears to have invalid JSON objects in the input stream (trailing commas after the `ItmId` keys).