# Add new array element to an existing JSON array using jq for sendgrid API

Tags: json, bash, sendgrid, jq

This question is related to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414854/add-json-array-element-with-jq-cmdline) one.

In my case, I would like to simply add individual elements. I have the following input.json.

```
{
  "content": [
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
  },
  "reply_to": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
    },
  "personalizations": [{
    "to": [{
        "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "email": "someotheremail@gmail.com"
      }]
    }]
}
```

I would like to append the subject and template_id so that the output.json looks like below.

```
{
  "content": [
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
  },
  "reply_to": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
    },
  "personalizations": [{
    "to": [{
        "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "email": "someotheremail@gmail.com"
      }],
    "subject": "Some subject"
    }],
    "template_id": "someID"
}
```

How would I do that with jq (including the syntax for input.json and output.json) in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple assignment:

```
jq '.template_id="someID" | .personalizations[0].subject="Some subject"' input.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "content": [],
  "from": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
  },
  "reply_to": {
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Some Name"
  },
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "email": "someotheremail@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "subject": "Some subject"
    }
  ],
  "template_id": "someID"
}
```